# Attaching attributes to Java methods

Tags: java, selenium

I am looking for a solution in Java to the next challenge, I am writing tests using Selenium and I would like to declare outside of each test-method the version of a website that it's compatible. The `compatibleVersion` variable should be accessible inside the method or by another method. Each method can has the same variable with a different value.

Probably I would use it, something like that.

```
@compatibleVersion = 1.1
public static test_UserSignUp(){
  if(currentSite < compatibleVersion){
     //do A
   } else {
      //do B
    }
}

@compatibleVersion = 1.2
public static test_UserSignUp(){
  if(currentSite < compatibleVersion){
     //do C
   } else {
      //do D
   }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Writing something yourself via annotations and reflections probably won't look very elegant. Would you be able to use JUnit 5 as part of your implementation? Also, why not just make the compatible version a final local variable at the start of each method?

Comment: @Dane White, thanks for the info. I found [that example very useful](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-custom-annotations-example/). I am going to invoke my tests instead of calling them. Can you please explain your idea with a final variable. Thanks!